# Best Practices to use AWS Secrets Manager on password rotation in Rest API using NodeJs Express Web Framework

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, express, aws-secrets-manager

Earlier I used MongoDB credentials in .env file and used in my REST APIs.
When I start the node js service(using pm2), the MongoDB connection is established in app.js it works well.

Later I replaced the credentials with AWS Secrets Manager then I fetch the credentials from the secrets manager and it worked well.

Now, I enabled password rotation for the secrets manager and it is updating the MongoDB connection password. Then my services are getting failed since I wrote the code to connect MongoDB in app.js file and which is run at the first time only. When I restart the code, services are working.

Can anyone suggest the best practice to use the secrets manager with rotation??

Please find my research

1. Need to trigger pm2 restart when the password rotation succeeds. But it causes downtime to services when someone already in use with the services. We cannot ensure when can the password rotation is started in aws. Ref:
   https://medium.com/@zaccharles/how-secrets-manager-schedules-automatic-rotations-e9f5f50de8aa
2. Need to have scheduled cloud watch to rotate the password and after the password rotation succeeds then need to restart the services. But with this, the services are not available 24X7
3. Need to invoke the services every time when any api is get invoked. But it is not a best practice and it causes delay to fetch credentials and connect to MongoDB database.

Answer (score 1):

For high availability rotation, use multi-user rotation. See this documentation for how to set that up  https://docs.aws.amazon.com/secretsmanager/latest/userguide/rotating-secrets-two-users.html